# Uploaded image using JSP gets corrupted

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page which I am using to upload an image. The image gets uploaded to the server but the size gets reduced and the file is getting corrupted. I am  using the code below for uploading the image file.

Could anyone please let me know what's the mistake am doing?

```
String contentType=request.getContentType();

if ((contentType!=null) && contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0))
{
    DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());

    int formDataLength=request.getContentLength();

    byte dataBytes[]=new byte[formDataLength];

    int totalBytesRead;

    while(totalBytesRead<formDataLength)
    {
        byteRead=in.read(dataBytes,totalBytesRead,formDataLength);

        totalBytesRead+=byteRead;
    }

    String file=new String(dataBytes);
    String saveFile=file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"")+10);

    saveFile=saveFile.substring(0,saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
    saveFile=saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, saveFile.indexOf("\""));

    int lastIndex=contentType.lastIndexOf("=");

    String boundary=contentType.substring(lastIndex+1,contentType.length());

    int pos;

    pos=file.indexOf("filename=\"");
    pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;
    pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;
    pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;

    int boundaryLocation=file.indexOf(boundary,pos);

    int startPos=((file.substring(0,pos)).getBytes()).length;

    int endPos=((file.substring(0,boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

    FileOutputStream fileOut=new FileOutputStream(sDir+"/"+lsNewName);

    fileOut.write(dataBytes,startPos,(endPOs-startPos));

    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
}
```

I have two instance 11i and R12 and I somehow find it strange that `endPos` and `boundarylocation` values are different in R12(new system) but are same in older system.

I also tried applying `Shift-JIS` encoding to `endPos` as below and it still didn't work

```
int endPos=((file.substring(0,boundaryLocation)).getBytes("Shift-JIS")).length;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please format the code in your question.

Comment: can anyone update on this?

Comment: can anyone help me on this am still stuck with this I passed the encoding as Shift JIS its reading within bounmds but the file is getting corrupted